# Assign Raster band to variable name in Loop - "can't assign" error

Tags: python, function, loops

I want to write two nested loops that iterate over the RGB bands of a series of eight JPG images. Later on these images shall be combined into one array channel by channel, so each array of the channels first has to have a proper name:

```
for ColorBand in [1, 2, 3]:
        for eighth in range(0,8):
            rastername="20140525-16-20-00_full_"+str(eighth)+"_0.jpg"
            raster =gdal.Open(rastername)
            band = raster.GetRasterBand(ColorBand)
            "eighth_"+str(eighth)+"_"+ColorBand = band.ReadAsArray()
```

Unfortunately, this returns a "can't assign to function call" error. I couldn't really find a proper answer how to solve this in other questions. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing `"eighth_"+str(eighth)+"_"+ColorBand = band.ReadAsArray()`? Are you trying to make a variable name on the fly? I really don't recommend that. Just add the value to a 2D list or something.

Comment: Well, it should assign the pixel values of the band to a string that is composed of "eighth_", then the number of the eighth (this is 360°images divided into eighths) and the number of the Band.
E.G. "eighth_5_1", which means the first band of the fifth eighth.
Your recommendation seems quite well, however, I ask myself why it does not work "On the fly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the line:

```
"eighth_"+str(eighth)+"_"+ColorBand = band.ReadAsArray()
```

It appears that you are trying to create a variable name and assign to it the result of `band.ReadAsArray()`.

You could create a dictionary, say `color_dict` and make `"eighth_"+str(eighth)+"_"+ColorBand` as the key and use it to assign the value of `band.ReadAsArray()`. i.e.,

```
color_dict = {}
color_dict["eighth_"+str(eighth)+"_"+ColorBand] = band.ReadAsArray()
```

Later in your code you can access this data as `color_dict["eighth_"+str(eighth)+"_"+ColorBand]`